# How to modify these icons in the Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, ide

Where are the resources for the code folding icons contained within Eclipse? Is there someone here familiar enough with the source code to direct me?

Thank you.

[Example http://codespunk.com/files/upload/eclipse_collapse.png](http://codespunk.com/files/upload/eclipse_collapse.png)

Comment: The icons are probably in a signed Eclipse jar which makes changing them difficult

Comment: I've extracted the resources from all of the jars and it doesn't appear to be in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images are `collapsed.png` and `expanded.png` in the `org.eclipse.jface.text` plugin in the `org.eclipse.jface.text.source.projection.images` folder.

They are used by the `org.eclipse.jface.text.source.projection.ProjectionAnnotation` class.

This plugin is signed, if you modify it Eclipse will complain.

Comment: Thank you! I was only examining jars which had an /icons folder. :)